# Gunicorn/nginx - Flask Application - Why is 2/5 requests freezing up on me.... But in incognito mode it never freezes up?

Tags: docker, performance, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have a flask application that is a simple single page web app that contains a form. When I launch it ONLY using flask I do not have the issue.

When I put it in a docker container and launch it with Nginx and Gunicorn then access my site the following issue arises...

When I submit the form 3/5 times it's perfectly fine but 2/5 times it freezes and takes 30 seconds to respond to my request the timing breakdown is almost always the same and goes as follows(request sent .10ms, waiting(TTFB) 30.89s, content download 1.56ms. When I try it in incognito mode I have No issues at all and it's nearly instant every time. Also, hitting submit a couple times when it's not responding breaks it from hanging up and results in a quick response.

I'm assuming this is a caching issue but I'm at a loss for how to diagnose the issue or why it's happening. With Chromes debugger it simply shows the |request(pending) type(document) time(pending)| and it's passing the form data that includes CSRF_Token.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you elaborate on where are you running your container? OS? resources (of the host machine and your container). Try to use `docker stats` to see if it's resources issue

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by reading up on using gunicorn for docker here: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/gunicorn-in-docker/

The issue I believe was that I needed to change the workers temporary directory to
--worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm  This seems to have fixed my issue.